# How to manage multiple types of send parameters in a single api call using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, multipart

How to manage the case if I only want to send text, or only image not both like this code does. As in this code volley gives error when either message or imageBitmap is not provided.

```
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, CHAT,
            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(MESSAGE, message);
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(FILE, new DataPart("Image.jpg", imageBitmap));
            return params;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```